# Installing BSNL UTStarCom 300R2U ADSL2+ Modem via USB port

Tags: networking, usb, network-manager, internet, modem

```
anoop@blackTiger:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0451:6060 Texas Instruments, Inc. RNDIS/BeWAN ADSL2+
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruszer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have a modem, UTStarCom 300R2U Modem. I need to install this using USB. I need to do this for demonstrating a concept to my friends. `lsusb` lists this device

**`Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0451:6060 Texas Instruments, Inc. RNDIS/BeWAN ADSL2+`**

It is installed but i need a better way to configure this adapter. My modem is configured to connect automatically to INTERNET(Always on option). Can anyone help me to use this modem via usb? pls.. I need to prove that linux is capable of doing everything...

Last few lines of `dmesg`

```
[   15.658156] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  270.29  Wed Feb 23 16:16:53 PST 2011
[   15.759823] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   17.397141] EXT4-fs (sdb1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[   20.086931] EXT4-fs (sdb1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[   25.080006] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[  165.201492] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, address 2
[  167.688012] usb 4-1: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 3
```

Ubuntu 10.10 fully updated..`sudo wvdialconf`

```
anoop@blackTiger:~$ sudo wvdialconf
[sudo] password for anoop: 
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3
```

Installation of ubuDSL fails.. My System just hangs after installation. Restarting solves the issue. But UbuDSL is not installed. Any work around for this?? I need configure this usb device as an Ethernet device(eth1) in networks. how do i set this? I pls help..

Answer (score 2):

If the DSL modem is not immediately recognize as an Ethernet interface when you plug it in (or when it's started an initialized and all), there's not much you will be able to do. This will probably require extra work to have a kernel driver support the modem since there is no ethernet interface exported and not serial device.

With no serial device (like *ttyUSB0* or something), you won't be able to use **wvdial** either.

Comment: Is there any alternate option? Can i make the USB connection to be a serial type ttyUSB0?

Comment: Depends on the devices, but this one doesn't appear like it's the case.